# Invalid Unicode string value in MySQL insert

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with a .sh script which copies a databse from remote google cloud storage. It's a mysql 8 databse. The problem now is that the remote database contains some Unicode emojis, which cause the import to fail with this message:

```
Error 1366 (HY000) at line 1439: Incorrect string value '\xF0\x9F\x9A...' for column 'name' at row 3201
```

I don't have many more infos about the system, but where should I look to find the cause of the problem? The databse seems to accept UTF-8 already.

Here are some infos I get from SHOW VARIABLES:
[image]

Is there anything that looks suspicious?

When I'm inserting some unicode text using an SQL client, there are no problems.

Comment: Make sure that the 2 versions of servers are the same as sometimes even the minor versions can make the difference.

Comment: Which utf8 encoding do you use in mysql? Mysql made a mistake years ago, when its utf8 implementation was up to 3 bytes only, not up to 4 bytes as utf8. What exactly is your encoding in mysql

Comment: I've added some info about the encoding. Is there something else I have to find out?

Comment: Check `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table you are trying to insert into. The variables you show don't determine the character encoding for a given table or column. You need to look at the DDL for the table, or view the column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to see its collation.

Comment: That said, I don't think 0xF09F9A is a valid UTF8 character. Either the data import is misaligning the characters, or else your data is not valid.

Comment: the SHOW CREATE TABLE command shows this info for the column where the import fails: `file_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
when I copy the failing insert query in the sql client, it runs without a problem. So I don't think the db encoding is the cause.

Comment: I verified that the database is not the problem. It fails somewhere else but I don't know where.